# How can I get catchError message from service method in component?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
getFinanceDetails(clientId: string, type: OnvioClientUpdateType): Observable <ClientFinance> {
  return this.getClientContactDetailsById(clientId, type).pipe(mergeMap((data: any) => {
    const clientFinanceDetails = this.clientContactDetailsByJsonData(data);
    return of(clientFinanceDetails);
  })).pipe(catchError(ExceptionHandler.handleError));
}
```

I am calling this function from component and this is my service method.So my question is,
How can I get this error which return in catcherror function because Observable ClientFinance is override my error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`throwError`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/throw.html) to throw it back.

Something like this:

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

getFinanceDetails(clientId: string, type: OnvioClientUpdateType): Observable <ClientFinance> {
  return this.getClientContactDetailsById(clientId, type)
    .pipe(
       mergeMap((data: any) => {
          const clientFinanceDetails = this.clientContactDetailsByJsonData(data);
          return of(clientFinanceDetails);
       }),
       catchError(error => throwError("Something went wrong: ", error))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle `catchError` as below

```
catchError(err => {
    console.log('Handle error locally and rethrow it..', err);
    ExceptionHandler.handleError;
    return throwError('Error occurred.', err);    
})
```